# when UTC time zone is changed manually in windows time function returns the same value( i.e., time_t secs ) of the before time zone value

Tags: c

Step:1 Set the time zone to (UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada) in windows.

Step:2 Checked the value of `time(&secs)` using a C Program, I got `secs = 1386043600`.

Step:3 Changed the time zone to (UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi manually.

Step:4 Checked the value of time(&secs). Again I got the same value, `secs = 1386043600`.

After this I have rebooted the machine and again checked the value of `time(&secs)`.
Now the value has changed to secs = 1386046505. Does this value gets effected only after rebooting the system?

Comment: time(&secs);  // Current time in GMT
tptr = localtime( &secs );
local_secs = mktime( tptr );
tptr = gmtime( &secs );
tptr->tm_isdst = -1;
gmt_secs = mktime( tptr );
diff_secs = (local_secs - gmt_secs);
*utc_bias = diff_secs/60;
printf("%d\n",*utc_bias);

Comment: i have used localtime asdefined in above comment....but i got the same result.

Comment: The difference between 1386043600 and 1386046505 is 2905 which is not event 1hour (~50min) considering you changed UTC-08:00 to UTC+05:30 the difference should had been much more, after reboot or not...

Comment: here utc-08:00 doesn't mean (8'o clock).My point is when i have changed the time zone the clock also changes...( doesn't matter how much it changes) so depend on the clock change , i should get different value of (time(&secs)).....but iam getting the same value before and after time zone changes.............

Comment: time() gives you the number of seconds since EPOCH. It does not care about your Timezone...

Comment: does time() gives number of seconds since EPOCH of current local time or UTC time.if current local time and UTC time are different, does gmtime(&secs) gives correct UTC time.

Comment: Everything you need to know about gmtime : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/gmtime/

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior. A `time_t` value is the number of seconds since midnight (GMT) on 1 January 1970 — as if every computer had a counter counting up by 1 every second from then, and the value is what `time()` returns. It is *intentionally* independent of the time zone your computer is set to use.

Comment: but if we edit the time zone..the time also changes....and hence no.of seconds elapsed since 1 january 1970 also changes ..... my question is why iam able to see this changes only after system reboot.

Comment: @mujtaba No. GMT/UTC is one fix time zone used for reference. You have to convert the time according to your time zone. IOW, if you change your time zone from +0100 to +0200, and at the same time advance the hour counter of your clock, the UTC time point stays the same.

Comment: ok..... do we have any other method to get the value of "(UTC-08:00)" from "(UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)" using MSDN functions.

Answer (score 0):

Trying running this sample code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<windows.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    time_t t,prev_t;
    int index=1;
    SYSTEMTIME st, lt;
    printf("\n\tSetting the Time Zone to \"Central Standard Time\"");
    system("RunDLL32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL timedate.cpl,,/Z Central Standard Time");

    prev_t = time(NULL) ;
    printf("\nStarting Timetick %d", prev_t);
    while (index<=9) 
     {

        if( index==5)
        {
            printf("\n\tSetting the Time Zone to \"Eastern Standard Time\"");
            system("RunDLL32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL timedate.cpl,,/Z Eastern Standard Time");
        }
        memset(&st,'\0',sizeof(st));
        memset(&lt,'\0',sizeof(lt));

        Sleep(1000);
        t=time(NULL);
        GetSystemTime(&st); /* UTC */
        GetLocalTime(&lt);  /* local */

        printf("\n[%d] system(utc): %02d:%02d:%02d, local: %02d:%02d:%02d, time()=%ld (diff=%ld)", index,st.wHour, st.wMinute,st.wSecond,lt.wHour,lt.wMinute,lt.wSecond,t, t- prev_t);

        prev_t=t;
        index++;

    }
}
```

1) At startup, sample sets the current Time Zone to "Central Standard Time". And, also prints the current time tick as returned by time().

2) Then it executes a loop 9 times. Every iteration of the loop finds UTC time, localtime and time ticks using function GetSystemTime(), GetLocalTime() and time() respectively. 
These values are printed along with the difference in the previous time tick.

3) At 5th iteration, the Time Zone is changed to "Eastern Standard Time".

4) Every iteration is executed with a time gap of one second, using function Sleep().

5) The Time Zone change in the sample is achieved with the function system().

This out put of the code

```
Setting the Time Zone to "Central Standard Time"
Starting Timetick 1385974984
[1] system(utc): 09:03:05, local: 14:33:05, time()=1385974985 (diff=1)
[2] system(utc): 09:03:06, local: 14:33:06, time()=1385974986 (diff=1)
[3] system(utc): 09:03:07, local: 14:33:07, time()=1385974987 (diff=1)
[4] system(utc): 09:03:08, local: 14:33:08, time()=1385974988 (diff=1)
        Setting the Time Zone to "Eastern Standard Time"
[5] system(utc): 09:03:12, local: 14:33:12, time()=1385974992 (diff=4)
[6] system(utc): 09:03:13, local: 14:33:13, time()=1385974993 (diff=1)
[7] system(utc): 09:03:14, local: 14:33:14, time()=1385974994 (diff=1)
[8] system(utc): 09:03:15, local: 14:33:15, time()=1385974995 (diff=1)
[9] system(utc): 09:03:16, local: 14:33:16, time()=1385974996 (diff=1)
Process returned 1385974996 (0x529C4CD4)   execution time : 13.397 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: no this is right. but after this if i changed the time zone manually... i get the same results...